# CSS Background Image using url() Not Displaying

Tags: css

I recently have being following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FazgJVnrVuI and I am up to a part where I am adding images (around 1 hour in). I have tried everything I could and still it doesnt show.  I would love some help. Thanks :)

Here is my code :

```
css

...

 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0% rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%), url('/images/pic2.jpg');

...
```

My file directory looks like this

Main folder

Images/

```
  pic1.svg

  pic2.jpg

  pic3.jpg
```

html and css all in the main folder.

This error also pops up

*invalid property value*

Comment: Did you look at the property values you were using? Your linear-gradient setting is invalid, it's lacking the comma needed between the different color settings. Check out the correct syntax on MDN for example and see if that cures things. If not, put a runnable snippet of code into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: If you want fill free to go to my github repo at

https://github.com/Kris-Zhang-122507/Blockdum

Comment: Sorry, no. SO wants the code within the question, not a link to another site - the problem will arise in future if that site disappears. Remember, SO is trying to build up a repository of useful answers for future readers, not just to solve a problem for one reader at one point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is both with the URL and linear-gradient or either of them. If your code is in main folder and images are in the images folder then URL should be
`url('images/pic2.png')`. Also, try to change the linear gradient to test if it works.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), url('images/pic2.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the path to your images is right, using VSC for example, you should automatically see if it's the right path cause typing it will make appear a kind of pop up, where you can choose your file's URL.